# ErrorException: imagecreatetruecolor(): Invalid image dimensions in file while Intervention\Image\Image::resize()

Tags: php, laravel, image, api, image-resizing

I'm working on Laravel project and I need resize image and return it from controller as file. If image has width or height parameter equals 0, I have to compute another parameter.
I tried it like this (as I found it in documentation of library http://image.intervention.io/api/resize):

```
public function viewImage($w, $h, $path){
    $image = Image::where('path', $path)->first();
    if($image){
        $manager = new ImageManager(array('driver' => 'gd'));
        if ($w === 0){
            $img = $manager->make(asset("storage/galleries/".$image->fullpath))
                ->resize($w, $h, function ($constraint) {
                    $constraint->aspectRatio();
                });
            return $img->response('jpg');
        }
        else{
            if ($h === 0){
                $img = $manager->make(asset("storage/galleries/".$image->fullpath))
                    ->resize($w, $h, function ($constraint) {
                        $constraint->aspectRatio();
                    });
                return $img->response('jpg');
            }
            $img = $manager->make(asset("storage/galleries/".$image->fullpath))->resize($w, $h);
            return $img->response('jpg');
        }
    }
...
```

But it gives me error like this:

```
ErrorException: imagecreatetruecolor(): Invalid image dimensions in file C:\xampp\htdocs\PROGRAMATOR.SK_API\vendor\intervention\image\src\Intervention\Image\Gd\Commands\ResizeCommand.php on line 47
```

I use Intervention\Image\Image library

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, route parameters in laravel return string. So `$w` and `$h` are strings.
You have these options

1. Convert `$w` and `$h` to int in the begginning of your function

   `$w = intval($w);`

   `$h = intval($h);`
2. Change your condition comparation. PHP is able to compare String and int values. Your current comparation returns false every time. Remember that `"0" === 0` will always result in `false` as php also compares variable type. However if you use `"0" == 0` this will return `true`.

Also in case of width or height being `0` or `"0"` change it to `null`, so resize method works as intended.

[Take a look at documentation once more](http://image.intervention.io/api/resize)